# jar from Main.class creation: no main manifest attribute, in jar

Tags: java

I need to create a jar file and not use maven or gradle packages.

First of all - I used all options that I saw in StackOverflow, so please, do not mark this question as `duplicated` if you are not sure about the solution that you will find - more of them I have tried.

**Project structure:**

```
\src
  ---\Main.java
  ---\A.java
  ---\B.java
```

**Steps**:

*1. Compiling:*

`javac \src\*.java`

- result:

```
\src
  ---\Main.class
  ---\A.class
  ---\B.class
```

*2. MANIFEST file created:*

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: src.Main
```

*3. Compiling to the jar:*

`jar cfm test.jar MANIFEST.MF src/`

*4. Launching:*

`java -jar test.jar`

result:

> no main manifest attribute, in test.jar

**Also I was trying following:**

`jar cvfe myjar.jar src.Main src\*.class`

and many other options - the same result

---

How to correctly create a jar file natively?

Comment: where did you put the manifest file? seems like you tried to put it in the src folder. Maybe you should have checked those other answers, that's not where the manifest file goes. You can also simply unzip your jar file, create the right directory for it, put the manifest file in it, and re-zip it

Comment: I also wonder the `no main manifest attribute` message, be sure to add a newline after the last attribute of `MANIFEST.MF` (best have an empty line as last line)

Comment: @Stultuske, thanks, I have tried the way you offered (edit Manifest inside jar) - not working. It seems I have some broken jdk on my laptop

Comment: **Why** don't use you Maven , Gradle, etc? What you're doing is not very portable.

Comment: @OneCricketeer I have to make a solution that has most lightweight jar file, and I supposed this way will produce more light jar file than thought maven. It seems I have no other choice. Nothing work.

Comment: Maven creates the exact same JAR file... It runs `javac` and `jar` on its own. You can use `jar -tf` to compare output.

Comment: @user16320675, This is the solution (new line). Thanks, will be good if you provide an answer - I'll accept him

Comment: @Valentyn done . BTW I think that using Maven, Gradle,... should produce the same JAR (if configured correctly), but I am not an *experts* on this both...

Comment: @user16320675 Thank you. Anyway, it was worth it, I learned an important nuance from u

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Name-Value lines of the Manifest file must be terminated by a newline (`CR LF`, `CR` or `LF`) according the [JAR Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/specs/jar/jar.html#name-value-pairs-and-sections):

> ```
> section:           *header +newline
> nonempty-section:  +header +newline
> newline:           CR LF | LF | CR (not followed by LF)
> header:            name : value
> ```

Since the manifest file contains `Main-Class: src.Main` but it is not being recognized ("no main manifest attribute..."), the newline is probably missing after that line - the last line.
Some editors do not add a newline at the end of the file.

To avoid that problem always include an empty line at the very end of the Manifest file.

<sub>very old *problem*, I would expect the `jar` tool to correct that, or at least warns about it</sub>

Answer (score 1):

## Project structure

```
DemoApp
├── MANIFEST.MF
└── src
    ├── A.java
    ├── B.java
    └── Main.java
```

### MANIFEST file

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: Main
```

### Main.java

**No package**

```
import java.util.Calendar;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello world!");
        System.out.println(new A().hello("WORLD"));
        System.out.println(new B().echo(Calendar.getInstance().getTime().toString()));
    }
}
```

## Steps

### 1. Compiling:

```
javac src/*.java -d out
```

#### result

```
DemoApp
└── out
    ├── A.class
    ├── B.class
    └── Main.class
```

### 2. Copy MANIFEST.MF to out

```
cp MANIFEST.MF out/
```

#### result

```
DemoApp
└── out
    ├── A.class
    ├── B.class
    ├── Main.class
    └── MANIFEST.MF
```

### 3. Packing jar

```
cd out
jar cfm ../app.jar MANIFEST.MF *.class
cd ..
```

#### final result

```
DemoApp
├── app.jar
├── MANIFEST.MF
├── out
│   ├── A.class
│   ├── B.class
│   ├── Main.class
│   └── MANIFEST.MF
└── src
    ├── A.java
    ├── B.java
    └── Main.java
```

### 4. Launching:

```
java -jar app.jar
```

## Jar file structure

```
app.jar
├── A.class
├── B.class
├── Main.class
└── META-INF
    └── MANIFEST.MF
```

## Project structure - No MANIFEST.MF

```
DemoApp
└── src
    ├── A.java
    ├── B.java
    └── Main.java
```

## Steps

### Compile .java

```
javac src/*.java -d out
```

#### Result

```
DemoApp
├── out
│   ├── A.class
│   ├── B.class
│   └── Main.class
└── src
    ├── A.java
    ├── B.java
    └── Main.java
```

### Packing jar

```
jar cfe app.jar Main -C out /
```

#### Result

```
DemoApp
├── app.jar
├── out
│   ├── A.class
│   ├── B.class
│   └── Main.class
└── src
    ├── A.java
    ├── B.java
    └── Main.java
```

### Launching:

```
java -jar app.jar
```

Comment: Thanks. But it seems I have some special jdk. nothing works for me

Comment: @ValentynHruzytskyi JDK shoudn't matter. Where exactly are you stuck in these steps?

Comment: Windows ? or Linux ? java version ? `javac -version`, My command is for linux, if you use windows , change **/** to  ``\``  , and  **cp** to **copy**

Comment: The manifest file isn't necessary. See my answer

Comment: @OneCricketeer, Yes , The manifest file isn't necessary.  scroll up my answer, include two version answer, use `jar cfe app.jar Main -C out /`

Answer (score 0):

```
$ java -version
java version "17.0.3" 2022-04-19 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 17.0.3+8-LTS-111)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.0.3+8-LTS-111, mixed mode, sharing)

$ javac -version
javac 17.0.3
```

Use a Makefile

```
JAVAC=javac
MAIN_CLASS=Main
APP_NAME=app
sources = $(wildcard src/*.java)
classes = $(sources:.java=.class)


all: program

program: $(classes)

clean:
    @rm -rf out/
    @rm *.jar

%.class: %.java
    @$(JAVAC) -d out $<

jar: $(classes)
    @jar -v --create --file $(APP_NAME).jar --main-class $(MAIN_CLASS) -C out/ .

exec: jar
    java -cp .:out -jar $(APP_NAME).jar

.PHONY: all program clean jar
```

Folder structure

```
├── Makefile
└── src
    └── Main.java
```

```
$ make clean exec
added manifest
adding: Main.class(in = 413) (out= 288)(deflated 30%)
java -cp .:out -jar app.jar
Hello world
```